# How to setup auto migrating core data stack with Magical Record?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is how I currently setup core data stack:

```
func setupCoreDataStack() {

    if NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.MR_defaultStoreCoordinator() != nil {
        return
    }

    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.MR_defaultManagedObjectModel()
    let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel!)
    var storePath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(PBOSharedGroupName)
    storePath = storePath!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("POSowner.sqlite")

    try! persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storePath, options: nil)
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator(persistentStoreCoordinator)
    NSManagedObjectContext.MR_initializeDefaultContextWithCoordinator(persistentStoreCoordinator)
}
```

but I do not know what to change to setup **auto migrating** core data stack.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add following options:

```
let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
```

as a parameter of `addPersistentStoreWithType:`